# TreeViewItem MouseDoubleClick event and MvvmLight

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

How do I set `CommandParameter` in the below code so that it will point to currently selected item?

```
<TreeView Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DockPanel.Dock="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ServerItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ConnectServer}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Databases}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

ViewModel code:

```
public RelayCommand<ServerItem> ConnectServer {
    get;
    private set;
}

ConnectServer = new RelayCommand<ServerItem>(param => ConnectToServer(param));

public void ConnectToServer(ServerItem item) {
    MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
}
```

Code execution doesn't get to `ConnectToServer` method because exception is thrown, telling me that cast from `System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs` to type `MadMin.Model.ServerItem` is not possible.

Comment: What about just `CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}"`? What does that return?

Comment: Ok, then how about `CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}}"`?

Comment: Damn, I'm an idiot - you answered me to similiar question some time ago with almost the same code you posted above... Thank you again. You can post your answer, so I could accept it.

Comment: It takes a while to get to grips with WPF, but it's well worth the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a [`RelativeSource Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in order to reach the `TreeView.SelectedItem` property from within the `Trigger`. Try this `Binding` for your `CommandParameter` instead:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}}"
```

Comment: One more question - I have two types of models in my `TreeView` - `ServerItem` and `DatabaseItem` (one contains another). If I use the code above, then if I doubleclick a `DatabaseItem` my `ConnectToServer` method will be called. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

```
{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}
```

Comment: I get `MouseButtonEventArgs` instead of selecteditem.